# Remove characters from dropdownlist into string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to remove stuff from specific text to grab a value.

Here is an example of the data in the dropdownlist:

```
665057 BC LTD / KX WHEELS -- 5380239 -- 
ABRAHAM CHEVROLET MIAMI INC -- 6574754 -- 
AC COLLINS FORD -- 418426 -- 
ACCESS FORD LTD -- 2322732 -- 
ACCESSOR-EASE -- 5809346 --
```

All I want to grab is the number for example:

> 5380239

from

> 665057 BC LTD / KX WHEELS -- 5380239 --

How would I do this?

Something like last index of? and before --?

Comment: Regular Expressions are your friend

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use it

Comment: Google is also your friend - try System.Text.RegularExpressions, or "regular expression to remove non-numeric characters" - you won't have to search for long..

Comment: I think something like index of would work, what have you tried?

Comment: @paqogomez but how do I return the first character of the number if it is always different? maybe by index of a space?

Comment: @BillyHoelJoel did you ever make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmHNz4) to demonstrate.

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("665057 BC LTD / KX WHEELS -- 5380239 -- ");       
list.Add("ABRAHAM CHEVROLET MIAMI INC -- 6574754 -- ");
list.Add("AC COLLINS FORD -- 418426 -- ");
list.Add("ACCESS FORD LTD -- 2322732 -- ");
list.Add("ACCESSOR-EASE -- 5809346 --");

var numbers = list.Select(e => e.Split(new [] {" --"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim());
foreach(var num in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Or if you wanted to do it with Regex:

```
string pattern = "(.*)(-- )(.*)( --)";
Regex r1 = new Regex(pattern);

foreach (string s in list)
{
    Match match = r1.Match(s);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string v = match.Groups[3].Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", v);
    }
}
```

[Regex fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OyKzF8)

Answer (score 1):

```
List (int) nValues = new List(int)()
foreach item in DropDownList.Items 
{
    nValues.Add(Int32.Parse(item.Split("--")[1].Trim()))
}

// Do something with the values
```

...ish. My C#'s a little rusty.

Comment: In fact, maybe even `foreach item in DropDownList.Items {...item.Text...}`

Comment: not sure this would work, all i need is the number out of the text i'm okay with making it a string tho